# Is it possible to check the code in STS(Spring Tool Suite) code using code45?Or do we need eclipse software for this?

Tags: development-environment

I am trying to use portify to check the code in STS(Spring Tool Suite). However, I am not sure if this is possible. Do I need eclipse software for this?

I am expecting to be able to use code45 to check the code in STS environment.